# How to change Register message in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, components, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 2.5 inbuilt registration form . Now i need change the display Message After successful register .(Your account has been created and an activation link has been sent to the email address you entered. Note that you must activate the account by clicking on the activation link when you get the email before you can log in.)

How to change this ?. Please help i have tried a lot . and all so tried to search related files but no use .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registration message comes from Language Variable `COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_ACTIVATE` defined in com_users language file

```
language\en-GB\en-GB.com_users.ini
```

Please check the below link how to override langauge -

http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Overrides_in_Joomla